# GPU load in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I just built TensorFlow v1.0 and I am trying to run MNIST test just to see if it's working. Seems like it is, but i am observing weird behaiviour. 
My system has two Tesla P100, and nvidia-smi shows the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 361.107                Driver Version: 361.107                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-SXM2...  Off  | 0002:01:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0   114W / 300W |  15063MiB / 16280MiB |     51%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P100-SXM2...  Off  | 0006:01:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   27C    P0    35W / 300W |  14941MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     67288    C   python3                                      15061MiB |
|    1     67288    C   python3                                      14939MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As it shown, python3 ate all the memory on both GPUs, but computational load are placed only on first.

Exporting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES I can limit GPU to be used, but it's not affect computational time. So no gain from adding second GPU. Single GPU

```
real    2m23.496s
user    4m26.597s
sys     0m12.587s
```

Two GPUs:

```
real    2m18.165s
user    4m18.625s
sys     0m12.958s
```

So the question is, how to load both GPUs?

Comment: What code are you running? maybe your optimization is only on the ops of one GPU but the variables are placed on both. Could you post the code?

Comment: Normally TF only uses one GPU, you need special multi-gpu architecture to utilize more than that (use `with tf.device("gpu:1")` to place things on gpu:1), see cifar multi-gpu offial example

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav, but why does it occupy 2 GPUs then?